# Disable the submit button after clicking and enable it back again after a few seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using jquery $.post when submitting a form. I want to disable the button for like 5 seconds after it has been clicked to avoid multiple submission of the form.

here's what I've done for now:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.post(base_url + 'folder/controller/function',$('#formID').serialize(),function(data){
        $('#message').slideDown().html('<span>'+data+'</span>');
    });
});
```

I've used fadeIn and fadeOut before, but still it doesn't work when I tested it clicking the button rapidly. What should I do to achieve what I wanted to happen?

Comment: $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');  $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');  Use this

Comment: What kind of button do you have? Is that `<input>`/`<button>` or `<div>`/`<span>`/`<a>`?

Comment: just a simple input type button.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do what you wanted like this:

```
var fewSeconds = 5;
$('#btn').click(function(){
    // Ajax request
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
    }, fewSeconds*1000);
});
```

or you can use jQuery's `.complete()` method which is being executed after the ajax receives a response:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    $.post(/*...*/).complete(function(){
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
    });
    btn.prop('disabled', true);

});
```

**edit:** [this is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/UDdaf/435/) with 3 seconds server-side response delay

---

#### Edit

Since even the answer is 8 years old, but still getting attention and jQuery is getting less popular I think it's worth adding example **without jQuery**

```js
const fewSeconds = 3
 
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.disabled = true
  setTimeout(() => {
   e.target.disabled = false
  }, fewSeconds * 1000)
})
```

```html
<input type='button' id="btn" value="click me" />
```

Comment: I'll try this one out. and see if it works. thank you so much for your response. :)

Comment: i can still do a rapid clicking using this script. or maybe because im running my script in localhost so the ajax response is much quicker.

Comment: im actually doing this to stop click events from some links in my site... the thing is that each time i click with about a thousanth of a second in between each click... it just doesn't care about this and it fires everything two times (or more if you clicked like crazy) is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The bottom linked JSFiddle example doesn't work due to - Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). I believe this is a newish browser policy.

Comment: @mikato I've updated the jsfiddle and It's working again

Answer (score 2):

Just place this in your JS for the page the submit button is on

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
    $("form").submit(function(){
      $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true).val("Please wait...");
      return true;
    })
  })
</script>
```

[Code source](https://recalll.co/app/?q=php%20-%20ZF2%20preventing%20multiple%20form%20submission%20-%20Stack%20Overflow)

Answer (score 2):

In extension of @Teneff answer if there is multiple submit button in the form and you want the name of button at server side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fewSeconds = 5;
$('button').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var text = btn.text();
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.prop('disabled', true);
        btn.text("Wait...");
    }, 10);
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
        btn.text( text);
    }, fewSeconds*1000);
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the .success function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) it's what you need.

so what you do is disable button on click

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    $.post(base_url + 'folder/controller/function', $('#formID').serialize(), function(data) {
        // code on completion here
        })
        .success(function() { 
           $('#btn').attr('disabled', false);
        })
    });
});
```

This way is better as what happens if your request takes more than 5 seconds to return?

Comment: I'll try this one out. and see if it works. thank you so much for your response. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure you can pass an object to `$.post` and what will happen if the `dataType` is not as defined, user will have to reload the page ?

Comment: You can't indeed, I need to edit that. should also use .ajax as opposed to .post/.get - http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/11/avoid-jquerypost-use-jqueryajax.html

Answer (score 1):

**Take any form of button and accrue its value to a variable. Replace the value with "please wait..." and after 5 seconds pass the previous saved variable back and disable to false.**

```
    $('input[type=submit], input[type=button]').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var textd = btn.attr("value");
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
    btn.attr('value', 'Please wait...');
    setTimeout(function(){
    btn.prop('disabled', false);
    btn.attr('value', textd);
    }, fewSeconds*1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

#### **Simple Solution:**

DOM query:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#your-button')
```

Add temporarilyDisableBtn() to eventListener:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // implementation
    temporarilyDisableBtn(btn)

    // your extra code here
}
```

Code to disable and re-enable btn:

```js
function temporarilyDisableBtn(btn) {
    btn.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(function () {
      btn.disabled = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

this is a general solution that will work for most implementations. More on [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('#btn').live('click', function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true).delay(800).prop('disabled', false);
        });
```

//Or

```
 $('#btn').live('click', function () {
            var obj = $(this);
            obj.prop('disabled', true);
            $.post(base_url + 'folder/controller/function', $('#formID').serialize(), function (data) {
                $('#message').slideDown().html('<span>' + data + '</span>');
                obj.prop('disabled', false);
            });
        });
```

Comment: [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) delays only items inside the animation queue

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. [source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)