# prevent click event for two seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want t0 enable click event after 2 seconds in jquery.I want to stop click event for 2 second and enable it after 2 seconds

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var i=0;
$('.clickBtn').click(function(event){
setTimeout(function(){
event.preventDefault();
},2000);
 
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clickBtn">click</a>
```

Comment: You will need to use the unbind http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable the submit button after clicking and enable it back again after a few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932766/disable-the-submit-button-after-clicking-and-enable-it-back-again-after-a-few-se)

Comment: this post should do what you want to achieve http://stackoverflow.com/a/10932857/7599559

Comment: I would just prevent the event at first and then delay the action by 2 second using a `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-div">
    <a class="clickBtn">click</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.clickBtn').addClass('non-clickable');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.clickBtn').removeClass('non-clickable');
    },2000);

    $('.click-div').on('click', '.clickBtn', function(event){
        if($(this).hasClass('non-clickable'))
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout` function to enable button after some time.
Use `prop` to add an attribute to your element.

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function() {

  // your button
  var mybutton = $(this);

 mybutton.prop('disabled', true);

  //Your ajax code

//remove disable attribute after 2 second.
  setTimeout(function() {
    mybutton.prop('disabled', false);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: You are telling exactly the same as this post  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10932857/7599559

Comment: @BrentBoden It's pretty simple and do not want to copy and paste anything :)